rational complex minmax
As the title says, I wanted to understand the following part of a proof in Guttel (Corollary 2, page 6). $f$ is an analytic function and $r_m \in \mathcal{P}_{m-1}/q_{m-1}$ is a rational function with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$ where the numerator are the polynomial of degree at most $m-1$ while the denominator is a fixed polynomial degree $m-1$ whose poles are non contained in a compact set $K$.
I wanted to understand whether $$||f - r_m||_{\infty, K}$$ has a minimum, i.e a rational complex minmax approximation or other condition are needed. Surely it's bounded since I can take $q_{m-1} \in \mathcal{P}_{m-1}/q_{m-1}$ giving $||f - 1||_{\infty, K} < \infty$
Any solution, counterexample or reference is appreciated.

$\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}$ is a finite dimensional vector space (of dimension $m$) hence it has a natural topology. We can use for example as a norm on it the following one,
$$
\left\|p\right\|_{\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}} = \left\|\frac{p}{q_m}\right\|_{\infty,K}.
$$
Introduce the function,
$$
\varphi : \left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
\mathcal{P}_{m - 1} & \rightarrow & \mathbb{R}_+\\
p & \mapsto & \displaystyle \left\|f - \frac{p}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K}
\end{array}
\right..
$$
For all $p_1,p_2$ in $\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}$, we have,
$$
|\varphi(p_1) - \varphi(p_2)| = \left|\left\|f - \frac{p_1}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K} - \left\|f - \frac{p_2}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K}\right| \leqslant \left\|\frac{p_1}{q_{m - 1}} - \frac{p_2}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K} = \left\|p_1 - p_2\right\|_{\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}}.
$$
It show that $\varphi$ is $1$-Lipschitz hence continuous.
Now, set $R = 2\|f\|_{\infty,K}$. If $\|p\|_{\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}} > R$, then,
$$
\varphi(p) = \left\|f - \frac{p}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K} \geqslant \left\|\frac{p}{q_{m - 1}}\right\|_{\infty,K} - \|f\|_{\infty,K} > 2\|f\|_{\infty,K} - \|f\|_{\infty,K} = \|f\|_{\infty,K} = \varphi(0).
$$
It proves that $\inf_{\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}}\{\varphi\} = \inf_{B(0,R)}\{\varphi\}$ where $B(0,1) \subset \mathcal{P}_{m - 1}$ is the closed ball of centre $0$ and radius $R$ for the norm $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}}$. Since $\mathcal{P}_{m - 1}$ is finite dimensional, $B(0,R)$ is compact hence the $\inf$ of the continuous function $\varphi$ is reached. It proves that indeed, $\|f - r_m\|_{\infty,K}$ reaches a minimum for $r_m \in \mathcal{P}_{m - 1}/q_{m - 1}$.
